# Need info on building stateless web app

Tags: php, javascript, api, session, authentication

If someone could point me to some good resources on building a stateless web app (or just give me some basics here), that would be great.

I am making a web app that has a presentation layer entirely in JS. It will interface with a RESTful API that I don't want to depend on sessions.

How can I manage an API and user authentication without sessions? (Please note I am doing this to learn more, not because it is necessarily the best solution for my web app)

Any info is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I am not opposed to using cookies to maintain state (as long as there is a secure way to do it), I just don't want a session opened on the server.

Comment: Do you mean session without cookies? You need a session either way because if not then you would need to be sending the user login details every single time someone requests a page and evaluate it against the database. Sessions without cookies are possible, with ?sessid=XXX parameter on the end of url.

Comment: @mkram0 i mean maintaining a users logged in state without sessions.

Comment: The web its self is stateless that is why session and cookies where invented ... remove them and you have a stateless web

Comment: @Baba i am not opposed to using cookies to maintain state, i just dont want to open a session on the server.

Comment: @tau you can't keep a user logged in without some session

Comment: @mkram0 well im looking for solutions that might involve storing an authentication token in cookies to make requests to the api, or something like that. i dont really know which is why i asked the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send all the authentication data in every request.